# string length condition not working for webhook

Tags: javascript

I'm still new to JavaScript but I wrote a small script that sends messages to a webhook. Which works great, but now I need to set some conditions to it before it may execute. The condition I wanted to set here was that the field "name" has to have a minimal length of 9 characters. I just can't find the fault in this if statement.

```
function json()
{
  if(document.getElementById('name').length >= 9)
  { 
    var msgJson = {
      "text": "success",
    };
  send(msgJson);
  }
}
```

Does anyone have the answer for me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this an input field? You need to chain a .value onto the end of the getElementById statement.

Comment: Yes it's a text input field in a form. So if I set it to .value, how can I chek the input character amount? Cause the input can be for example "peter" and than the condition of 9 characters is not met.

Comment: Martin's answer will explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('name')` returns HTML element reference. If you want to check the length of that input value (`<input id="name">`), then you need to use `document.getElementById('name').value` and check the `length` of it, like this:

```
function json() {
    var el = document.getElementById('name');
    if (el.value.length >= 9) {
        var msgJson = {
            "text": "succes",
        };
        send(msgJson);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementById()` function returns an Element object ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)).  This has no `.length` property- so you are going to get an error.